# make a nested dictionary into flat by replacing a key with its values

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, key-value

I have this dictionary:

```
{   ‘Conversation 1’: {   ‘Date of Conversation’: 
                                     {   ‘Day of conversation’: None,
                                         ‘Month of conversation’: None,
                                         ‘Recent day of conversation’: None,
                                         ‘Time of conversation’: ‘15:26’,
                                         ‘Year of conversation’: None},
                          ‘Name of Candidate’: ‘CENSORED’},
    ‘Conversation 2’: {   ‘Date of Conversation’: 
                                     {   ‘Day of conversation’: ‘10’,
                                         ‘Month of conversation’: 'Jan',
                                         ‘Recent day of conversation’: None,
                                         ‘Time of conversation’: None,
                                         ‘Year of conversation’: None},
                          ‘Name of Candidate’: ‘CENSORED’}
}
```

as you can observe, it is a nested dictionary, but my target is to make this nested dictionary in a flat dictionary.

Specifically, I have to replace the key 'Date of Conversation' with its values. In this way, I want to achieve the following structure:

```
{   ‘Conversation 1’: {   ‘Day of conversation’: None,
                          ‘Month of conversation’: None,
                          ‘Recent day of conversation’: None,
                          ‘Time of conversation’: ‘15:26’,
                          ‘Year of conversation’: None},
                          ‘Name of Candidate’: ‘CENSORED’},
    ‘Conversation 2’: {  ‘Day of conversation’: ‘10’,
                         ‘Month of conversation’: 'Jan',
                         ‘Recent day of conversation’: None,
                         ‘Time of conversation’: None,
                         ‘Year of conversation’: None},
                         ‘Name of Candidate’: ‘CENSORED’}
}
```

I imagine that a replace function is needed in this case, however I don't understand what is a good procedure to replace a key with its value and to make a nested dictionary as a flat one.

Comment: use a dict comprehension, {k: f(v) for k, v in data.items()}, such that the function "f(v : dict) -> dict" takes the value it has now, and returns the value you want.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  If you are asking for someone to improve upon an algorithm you have in mind, please state that and provide a text description of the algorithm that you have come up with.